# Issues with css , word wrapping too early cant find solution

Tags: css

http://webdesigncom.net/_sites/jsw/Judge

At the link above I have a 600px div box next to each team member's picture. The paragraph next to it is wrapping too early on so many lines. I have no idea why, I have tried searching the internet and frankly this is my first time posting here, just cant find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some relevant code (and maybe a JSFiddle example) here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: External link is now dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that there are many no-break spaces, written as `&nbsp;` entity references, where normal spaces should appear. There is no way to fix this in CSS; the content needs to be modified, but hopefully you can do some global search and replace that turns the no-break spaces to normal spaces.

For example, the markup contains `art book,&nbsp;<em>The World`, which prevents the browser from breaking after the comma—the no-break space forces the browser to keep “book, *The*” on one line.

I have no idea of where the no-break spaces have come from, but I have seen Content Management Systems turn spaces to no-break spaces apparently at random.

Comment: Thanks a million! i didn't even think of that i am using CKEditor any idea how to disable the &nbsp; tags i will do some research of my own

Answer (score 0):

try adding `diplay:block` to the div having `class=ShortBox`

Answer (score 0):

add "padding-left: 320px;" to the div.ShortBox css, where 320px would be the width of your image